# Why doesn't my page auto refresh properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, addeventlistener, page-refresh

My goal is to refresh the page when the class `p.fancybox-error` is visible, but I would like to know why this part of the code doesn't work at the top of my page.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  var theDiv = document.querySelector("p.fancybox-error");
  theDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000);
  });
</script>
```

I put it under this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

But it gives me this error:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'theDiv.addEventListener')

Thanks a lot guys, just take a look to @Stephane's answer, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: You are including jquery, but you are not using it.

Comment: i including it to know if i have to use it instead, perhaps jquery will be better than js

Comment: `document.querySelector("p.fancybox-error")` runs instantly and finds nothing, so returns null. then you try to addeventlistener to null. that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Since your code is at the top of your page, your `p.fancybox-error` does not exist yet when this JS code is executed. Wait for the document to be loaded by wrapping your code in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /* your code */ }, true);`

Comment: ah ok and you think I have to put it at the end of the page or can I add timer to let it find my class @StephenBugsKamenar

Comment: why is your example code on `click` but you said "when visible". what do you want?

Comment: i would like to refresh my page automatically only when the class p.fancybox-error appears, not before @StephenBugsKamenar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This polls every second looking for your class and auto-reloads when it exists

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if($("p.fancybox-error").length) location.reload();
  }, 1000);
});
```